# regex minus numbers

Tags: regex

I want to validate number that don't contain the minus char. The number > 0.

Have you got a regex for that ?

Comment: Neagtive lookbehind is your friend, try `(?<!-)[\d]+`

Comment: @Yaron you don't need to do a costly match with a negative lookbehind

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ but if it's not at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @Yaron ah yes, good thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusivly non-negativ numbers with decimal-point: `^\d+(?:.\d+)?$`, or capturing with negativ look-behind `((?<!-)[[:digit:]]+)` or a myriad other ways depending on the flavour of regex you need and the real problem at hand.

Comment: I like the non capturing group in this. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

**To match absolutes**

```
^\d+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/O4nGl5/2

**To match decimals**

```
^\d+(\.?\d+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/O4nGl5/3

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways to do that, one of them is:

`^[0-9]+$` (for integer numbers)

It checks your input against:

- Starts and ends with an integer (`^` for beginning and `$` for end)
- characters between between 0 and 9 (integers)
- 1 or more occurence (`+` for 1 or more occurrences of the previous expression)

Comment: Well, depends on the requirements, but normally I wouldn't consider 00000000000000114 as a valid integer. So more like `^0|([1-9][0-9]*)$`

Comment: `00000000000000114` is a valid integer though. Why wouldn't you consider it a valid integer?